# Oracle query mistake

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to know where the mistake is in this oracle query?

```
SELECT(KEY1),COUNT(*) FROM TABLE1 GROUP BY AGE
```

Comment: Is there an error message or is this homework?

Comment: SELECT KEY1 ,AGE  , COUNT(*)  FROM  TABLE1 GROUP BY KEY1,AGE

Comment: Yes, please add an error and what is it you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SELECT KEY1,COUNT(*) FROM TABLE1 GROUP BY KEY1`

There are two problems. First one: You cannot close the parenthesis after the first keyword. Second: You have to group by all keys that are in the query that are not all row dependend. In that case "KEY1". If you want to order by age you have to query age as parameter.

`SELECT AGE,COUNT(*) FROM TABLE1 GROUP BY AGE`

Your table naming is not very good. I assume you should have a look at group by tutorials like https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp or the sql tutorial https://www.w3schools.com/sql/

Answer (score 0):

Your query had an issue. You have to modify your query as below

```
SELECT KEY1,COUNT(*) FROM TABLE1 GROUP BY KEY1.
```

Observation:

All the columns that are added in the select statement alongside the aggregate functions, should be included the group by columns.

Your first column does have the bracket in it which should be removed.